# Showing the Previous URL after redirecting to another url

Tags: apache, dns

I have a retail application that is hosted at [www.emenu.com](http://www.emenu.com). My clients have there on websites that are hosted on their server, like [www.fastfood.com](http://www.fastfood.com), [www.freshlime.com](http://www.freshlime.com), etc. There is a button on their website which redirects to [www.emenu.com](http://www.emenu.com).

- [www.fastfood.com](http://www.fastfood.com) on a button click redirect to [www.emenu.com](http://www.emenu.com)
- [www.freshlime.com](http://www.freshlime.com) on a button click redirect to [www.emenu.com](http://www.emenu.com) like that,

Problem is that the client does not want to show my application URL in the address bar after redirecting.
ie, [www.fastfood.com](http://www.fastfood.com) will redirect to [www.emenu.com](http://www.emenu.com) but it should show [www.fastfood.com](http://www.fastfood.com) in URL.

I am using laravel for the development. Came across many solutions involving .htaccess like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?emenu\.come$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.fastfood.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,P]
```

But the solution doesn't work.

Comment: Could you not iframe the page into their website? Or potentially look at a `CNAME` type setup. What you're essentially looking for is custom domains and this article *might* shed some light on it with laravel - https://joelennon.com/dynamic-custom-domain-routing-in-laravel (**Note:** *I don't develop with Laravel so this is just a suggestion*)

Comment: This question is not about laravel. It's about `apache` and `dns`

Comment: You can’t show a URL different from the one you’re on. If they have a site on their domain, and your site is supposed to be shown as one of their subpages, then you pretty much only have two choices: they embed your site as an iframe on some of their pages, or they set up their web server to reverse-proxy certain URLs on their domain to your server.

Comment: @deceze My site is not a subpage. Their site is just an HTML, CSS website. They are using my application for order system, inventory management, hr, billing, reports, etc. Also, I have full permission on their domain and server.

Comment: But their domain is already pointed to their server and their server is already serving a page there. They want to integrate your app to serve some sub pages on their existing domain, right?

Comment: @deceze Yes,  My application is providing the facility for online ordering and other things I mentioned above. And they don't like users to see my application URL on the address bar.

Answer (score 1):

The way websites work is like this:

- user enters URL into browser (or clicks a link to get there), say `www.example.com/foo/bar`
- the browser/OS looks up the A or AAAA DNS record for `www.example.com`, this DNS record points to an IP address
- the browser sends an HTTP request to that IP address, like:

  ```
  GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
  Host: www.example.com
  ```
- the server at that IP address (hopefully) responds with some HTML

So you see, if the domain `www.example.com` is already pointed at your client's server, it can't also point at your server. And the URL in the browser's address bar will always show the URL it's currently actually loading, you can't mask that. If you want the contents of your site to appear on your client's domain name, then the server pointed to by the DNS record for that domain actually needs to return the HTML for your site. You pretty much have two options there:

1. Embed your site in an iframe on your client's page. Say `www.example.com/emenu.html` contains:

   ```
   <iframe src="http://www.emenu.com"></iframe>
   ```

   Then visitors going to `www.example.com/emenu.html` will see the content of your site (embedded into a site of your client).
2. Set up the web server for `www.example.com` to reverse-proxy (some of) your URLs. [In Apache that can be done with something like](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html):

   ```
   ProxyPass "/emenu"  "http://www.emenu.com/"
   ProxyPassReverse "/emenu"  "http://www.emenu.com/"
   ```

   Any HTTP request for the URL path `/emenu` to `www.example.com` would be forwarded by that server to your server, and the response be presented to the visitor as if the `www.example.com` server had produced it itself.